# How to compile expression which returns a pure function?

Tags: functions

Using Mathematica  the definition of user functions , which return "pure functions" is quite easy

```
f[list_] := Function[t, Sin[list[[1]] t] + list[[2]] Cos[t]]
Plot[f[{2, 1}][t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and often very useful. Please note the use of `f[liste][time]` with separated argument brackets.

**My question**: 
Is it possible to pre-compile the part `f[list]` in such a way that it returns a pure function object?

here a small example to clarify my question:

```
pg[a_(*liste *)] := Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {.4, a[[1]]}, {.8, a[[2]]}, {1, 1}} , InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

defines a polygon with two variable points. pg[a] is a pure function object
which can be used to find the polygon `pg[a][x]~=x`

```
opt = NMinimize[Sum[(trapez[{a, b}][x] - x)^2, {x, 0, 1, .2}], {a, b}]
```

Comment: It is not clear to me why you want to compile the _creation_ of the actual function. Oftentimes, it will be helpful enough to create the function only once, like in `f[list_] := Function[t, Evaluate[Sin[list[[1]] t] + list[[2]] Cos[t]]];
g = f[{2, 1}];
Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: Thanks! My intention is to create an approximation function , which depends on a list of paramaters. Something like `Interpoaltion[data[parameters]] ` These parameters are evaluated in a minimization process(involving NDSOlve,NMinimize), which calls the function  repeatedly.   For performance issues I would like to try a compiled version.

Comment: Hm. I don't get it. Would you please try to give a more concrete example that emphasizes where the performance bottleneck is? Btw.: Compiled functions cannot return a pure function. And if complex functions such as `NMinimize` or `NDSolve` appear in the code, it is usually not a good idea to compile it. But there might be other ways to speed up your code.

Answer (score 8):

Here is simple code to get you going:

```
Clear[inferType];
inferType[arg_Integer] := _Integer
inferType[arg:_Real | _?NumericQ /; Re[arg]==arg] := _Real
inferType[arg_List] /; ArrayQ[arg,_,IntegerQ]:=   
   {_Integer,Length[Dimensions[arg]]};
inferType[arg_List] /; ArrayQ[arg,_,NumericQ] && Re[arg]==arg:=
   {_Real,Length[Dimensions[arg]]};
inferType[_]:= General;

ClearAll[memoize, compile, $preprocessingRules]

$preprocessingRules  = {
   p: HoldPattern[Part[list:{__Integer}, part_Integer]] :> 
      RuleCondition[p]
};

memoize[fn:HoldPattern[Function[var_, body_]], General]:= compile[fn] = fn

memoize[fn:HoldPattern[Function[var_, body_]], {t__} | t__] := compile[fn] =  
    Replace[
        ReplaceAll[Hold[body], $preprocessingRules],
        Hold[preprocessed_] :> Compile[{{var, t}}, preprocessed]
    ]

compile[fn:HoldPattern[Function[var_, body_]]][arg_]:= 
    memoize[fn, inferType[arg]][arg]
```

And then

```
f[list_]:=compile[Function[t,Sin[list[[1]] t]+list[[2]] Cos[t]]]
```

and

```
Plot[f[{2, 1}][t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

You can check what function was generated by calling

```
?compile
```

Both type-inferencer and preprocessor are very simplistic, and this is for one - argument function only, but this can be a starting point, if you want this kind of things.

Comment: Thank you for your tough answer, I will need a nonpredictable amount of time to understand it....

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I will try to add some explanations when I get a spare moment.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort!.

Comment: What do you think about this variant `Compile[{{list , _Real, 1}}, 
 Function[t, Sin[list[[1]] t] + list[[2]] Cos[t]] &]`? What is the difference to your solution? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  The difference is that my code gets compiled dynamically, already after `list` variable value gets injected into `Compile`. Your suggestion won't work as intended, because `Compile` can't return a compiled pure function, and so the `Function` will remain uncompiled.

Comment: Tricky, my approach couldn't. work...Thanks